# Software for simulating supersonic aerodynamics

Tags: simulations, software

Could you please suggest the software, where I can load my 3D model and see how it behave on various conditions (speed - preferably including supersonic, temperature, pressure)?

Both free & commercial variants are interesting.

Comment: I think this is too far off topic from physics; it really falls under the realm of aerospace engineering. But since it concerns software, you could perhaps try asking on Super User (since I don't think there is another SE site that focuses on engineering).

Comment: Well, it would not be answered on SU, and as long as [Computational Science is stuck on Area](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/320/shall-we-unite-computational-science-proposals), I think we should give it a chance.

Comment: @David: While I agree that this sounds like an engineers tool, I'll offer a possible use case for physics. I don't know if the CFD people use Monte Carlo the way nuclear and particle physicists do, but if they did one of the tools they'd want is a whole experiment simulator for judging feasibility, and this is roughly what it would look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something that looks working and don't care much about the details, the standard solution is Fluent.
The nearest Open Source option is [OpenFoam](http://www.openfoam.com/).